# Codeigniter jquery form submit without refresh

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

i made this form but it doesn't want to redirect to the result page.

CONTROLLER

```
   function succeded()
{
        $this->load->view('wifi/header');
        $this->load->view('wifi/result-post-wifi');
        $this->load->view('wifi/footer');
}       
    function wifi_sign_up()                
{
            $tableName = "wifi_regs";
    $data['datetime_registrasi']        = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',now($this->input->post('datetime_registrasi')));               
            $data['nomor_registrasi']           = $this->wifi_model->getRegid($this->input->post('regid'));
            $data['username']                   = $this->input->post('inputUsername');
    $data['password']                   = md5($this->input->post('inputPassword'));
            $data['nama_lengkap']               = $this->input->post('inputNamaLengkap');
    $data['nomor_hp']                   = $this->input->post('inputNomorHP');
    $data['email']                      = $this->input->post('inputEmail');
    $data['paket']                      = $this->input->post('inputPaket');
    $data['metode_bayar']               = $this->input->post('inputMetodePembayaran');
            $data['jml_transfer']               = $this->input->post('inputPaket')+$this->wifi_model->getKodeRegistrasi($this->input->post('kode_registrasi'));            
            $data['bank_transfer']              = $this->input->post('inputBankPembayaran');
    $data['kode_registrasi']            = $this->wifi_model->getKodeRegistrasi($this->input->post('kode_registrasi'));
    $data['status_registrasi']          = $this->wifi_model->getStatusRegistrasi($this->input->post('status_registrasi'));
            $data['status_transfer']            = $this->wifi_model->getStatusTransferWifi($this->input->post('status_transfer'));


            if($this->wifi_model->insert_data($tableName, $data))
            {
                header("Content-type: application/json");
                header("HTTP/1.1: 200"); 
                header("status: 200");
                header("message : Register Berhasil");
                echo "{\"data\":" .json_encode($data). "}";
            }
        redirect('wifi/result-post-wifi', $data);
```

MODEL

```
   public function insert_data($tableName, $data) {
     return $this->db->insert($tableName, $data);
   }
```

VIEW

```
                          <div id="result-post-wifi"></div>                              
                            <form role="form" id="form-wifi" class="form-wifi" onsubmit="return registrasi('wifi');">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="username_wifi" placeholder="Username..." class="form-username form-control" id="username_wifi" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password_wifi" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="password_wifi" required>
                                </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-password_2">Confirm Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" name="password_2_wifi" placeholder="Confirm Password..." class="form-password_2 form-control" id="password_2_wifi" required>
                                </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-nama">Nama Lengkap</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="nama_lengkap_wifi" placeholder="Nama Lengkap..." class="form-username form-control" id="nama_lengkap_wifi" required>
                                </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-nomor_hp">Nomor HP</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="nomor_hp_wifi" placeholder="Nomor HP..." class="form-nomor-hp form-control" id="nomor_hp_wifi" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="email_wifi" placeholder="Email..." class="form-email form-control" id="email_wifi" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-email">Paket</label>
                                                      <select name="paket_wifi" id="paket_wifi" class="form-control" required>
                                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Pilih Paket</option>
                                                        <option value="1">Paket 1</option>
                                                        <option value="2">Paket 2</option>
                                                        <option value="3">Paket 3</option>
                                                      </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-pembayaran-wifi">Metode Pembayaran</label>
                                                      <select name="pembayaran_wifi" id="pembayaran_wifi" class="form-control" onChange="set_metode_pembayaran(this.value, 'wifi')" required>
                                                        <option value="1" selected="selected">Transfer Bank</option>
                                                        <option value="2">Cash/ Tunai</option>
                                                      </select>
                                            </div>
                                <div class="form-group" id="metode_pembayaran_wifi">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="form-metode-pembayaran">Paket Wifi</label>
                                                      <select name="bank_pembayaran_wifi" id="bank_pembayaran_wifi" class="form-control">
                                                        <option value="" selected="selected">Pilih Bank</option>
                                                        <option value="1">Bank 1</option>
                                                        <option value="2">Bank 2</option>
                                                        <option value="3">Bank 3</option>
                                                        <option value="4">Bank 4</option>
                                                      </select>                                                 
                                            </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn"><strong> REGISTRASI SEKARANG </strong></button>
                            </form>
                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

RESULT

```
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Nomor Registrasi </label>
                                                    <div class="form-email info-label"><?php  echo $nomor_regisrasi ?></div>       
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Status Registrasi </label>
                                                    <div class="form-email info-label"><?php  echo $status_regisrasi ?></div>                                                 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Username </label>
                                                    <div class="form-email info-label"><?php  echo $username ?></div>                                                  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Nama Lengkap  </label>
                                                    <div class="form-email info-label"><?php echo $nama_lengkap ?></div>                                                  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Nomor HP </label>
                                                    <div class="form-email info-label"><?php echo $nomor_hp ?></div>                                                  
                                            </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Email</label>
                                                    <div class="form-email info-label"><?php echo $email ?></div>                                                  
                                            </div> 
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Paket</label>
                                                    <div class="form-email info-label"><?php echo $paket ?></div>                                                  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Jumlah Transfer</label>
                                                    <div class="form-email info-label"><?php echo $jml_transfer ?></div>                                                
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Pembayaran Melalui</label>
                                                    <div class="form-email info-label"><?php echo $metode_bayar ?></div>                                                
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Nomor Rekening</label>
                                                    <div class="form-email info-label"><?php echo $nomor_rekening ?></div>                                                  
                                            </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Atas Nama</label>
                                                    <div class="form-email info-label"><?php echo $atas_nama ?></div>                                                  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group"> 
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-xs-5 control-label">Informasi Registrasi</label>
                                                    <label class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.open( 'http://www.domain.com', '_blank' )"><strong> DETAIL </strong></label>                                                  
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.open( 'http://www.domain.com', '_blank' )"><strong> BAYAR SEKARANG </strong></button>
                                            </div>
                            </form>
                </div>
                    </div>
             </div>
```

SCRIPT

```
function registrasi(jp, regid)
{    
            if(regid === undefined)
            {
                    regid = '';
            }
$('#result-post-' + jp).html('<div class="alert alert-info">Mengirimkan Data Registrasi ...</div>');
    var sd = "";
                if(jp == 'wifi' || jp == 'webservice')
        {
            sd = "inputUsername=" + $('#username_' + jp).val() + "&inputPassword=" + $('#password_' + jp).val() + "&inputNamaLengkap=" + $('#nama_lengkap_' + jp).val() + "&inputNomorHP=" + $('#nomor_hp_' + jp).val() + "&inputEmail=" + $('#email_' + jp).val() + "&inputPaket=" + $('#paket_' + jp).val() + "&inputBankPembayaran=" + $('#bank_pembayaran_' + jp).val() + "&inputMetodePembayaran=" + $('#pembayaran_' + jp).val();
        }

            if(sd.length > 0)
    {
    $.ajax({
                dataType     : "json",
        type     : "POST",
        url      : "wifi/sign_up",
        data     : sd + "&jp=" + jp + "&regid=" + regid,
        success  : function(res){ set_result(res, jp) ; },
            error        : function()
                            { 
                            $('#result-post-' + jp).html('<div class="alert alert-warning">Gagal mengirim data Registrasi.</div>'); 
                            }, 
                timeout: 50000          
    });
        }
    return false;

     }
    function set_result(res, jp)
{
    $('#result-post-' + jp).removeAttr('style');        
    if(res.status == 200 || res.status == 102)
    {
        $('#result-post-' + jp).html('');
        $('#result-post-' + jp).removeAttr('style');
        if(res.data == undefined)
        {
            $('#result-post-' + jp).html(res.message);              
        }
        else
        {
            $('#form-' + jp).attr({style : 'display:none;'})
            $('#result-post-' + jp).html(res.message + res.data);
        }
    }
    else if(res.status == 101)
    {
        $('#result-post-' + jp).html(res.message);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#result-post-' + jp).html(res.message);
    }       
}

function open_form(jp)
{
    $('#form-' + jp)[0].reset();
    $('#form-' + jp).removeAttr('style');
    $('#meto?de_pembayaran_' + jp).removeAttr('style');
    $('#result-post-' + jp).html('');           
}
```

i would be very thankful any kind of help

Comment: You can't use `redirect()` during `ajax request`. You have to redirect after `ajax request` through `jquery`.

Comment: thanks yash, but is there code for the jquery, even it could be redirect, to the result page, the form doesn'tt input to the mysql and doesn't fetch the form data.